# Remove element of array by its position

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I delete an array item if I know the index?

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
    setItems(prevState => prevState.filter((item) => item.index !== index));
}
```

item.index doesn´t exist. thank you!

also.. is this way faster than?

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
    setItems((prevState) => prevState.splice(index - 1, 1));
}
```

Comment: filter accepts extra parameters so change your filter callback to `.filter((item,idx) => idx !== index) `

Comment: Pretty much every possible way to do this has been covered here: [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` function can take a 2nd argument which is element index

```
deleteItem = (index) => {
    setItems(prevState => prevState.filter((item, i) => (i !== index)));
}
```

Comment: is this the preferred way or prevState.splice(index - 1, 1) ?

Comment: Yes if it depends only on index splice is better. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435141/remove-object-in-array-using-filter-and-splice-which-one-is-best-approach-in-ang