# is filter best way to remove items in array? (react.js)

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and making todo app and etc.
but all the tutorial only shows using filter to remove items in array.
I'll show you simple code.

```
const ProductItem = () => {
  const [users, setUser] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "jenny" },
    { id: 2, name: "tom" },
    { id: 3, name: "juan" },
  ]);
  const removeUser = (user) => {
    //this is filter way
    // let newList = users.filter((x) => x.id !== user.id);
    // setUser([...newList]);
//this is delete item by index way
    users.splice(users.indexOf(user), 1);
    setUser([...users]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {users &&
        users.map((x) => (
          <div key={x.id}>
            <li>{x.name}</li>
            <button onClick={() => removeUser(x)}>remove</button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductItem;
```

and both way is working correctly , but I just wonder if there's any reason that peoples using filter way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435141/remove-object-in-array-using-filter-and-splice-which-one-is-best-approach-in-ang this might help you

Comment: Splice mutates the array. Don't use it with react state, unless you copy the array first, since react depends on immutable state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule to use `.filter` all the time.

#### but all the tutorial only shows using filter to remove items in array.

Below are the main reasons:

> `.filter` always returns a **new array** with the results and keep the original array intact.

> **React** won't perform re-rendering if the reference has not changed or if it's mutated.

In your case, you can write `setUser` in one line a below if you use `.filter`

```
setUser(users.filter((x) => x.id !== user.id));
```

Where as `.splice` mutates the original `users` array and you should use **spread operator** while setting data with `setUser` else **React** won't perform re-rendering of component.

Remember one thumb rule **less lines of code ~ less bugs**.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, an array's length can be changed after it is initialized.

(I.E., a Javascript Array can be updated like a Linked List of C language)

---

**splice()** function can perform **add** and **remove** operations on an array.

**splice()** can be used when the requirement is to update the original data.

**More information on splice():**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

---

**filter()** function only selects a subset of elements that match a criteria, but does not delete anything from the original array.

filter() function need to be used when the original data must be kept intact.

**More information on filter():**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp